# How does parameter passing for the g++ equivalent for __declspec ( naked ) work?

Tags: assembly, g++

I am currently modifying code created in the MS VS IDE, and one change I need to make is the change from `__declspec (naked)` to `__attribute__ (( naked ))`.

After I made this change however, the program does not access and change parameters correctly.

Is the parameter passing different using `__attribute__ (( naked ))`?

Here is the code:

```
//Main file
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void test(int * arrayToSort, int size);


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int * a = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * 10);

    int j;
    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        printf("a[%d]=",j);
        scanf("%d",a+j);
        printf("\n");
    }

    test(a, 10);

    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
         printf("%d ", a[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//test code file
void test(int * array, int size)
{
    _asm {
        push edx
        push ecx
        push ebx
        push eax

        mov eax, dword ptr[esp+20] //*array
        mov ebx, dword ptr[esp+24] //size

        mov dword ptr[eax], 25 //array[0] = 25
        mov dword ptr[eax+4], ebx //array[1] = size

        pop eax
        pop ebx
        pop ecx
        pop edx
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

System specifications:

MacBook Pro Late 2009 Intel Core2 Duo 2.66 GHz running OS X Lion

Current Compilation instructions:

```
g++ -fomit-frame-pointer -m32 -fasm-blocks -o QS Test.cpp Main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GNU documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> naked
>   Use this attribute on the ARM, AVR, MCORE, RX and SPU ports to indicate that the specified function does not need prologue/epilogue sequences generated by the compiler.

`__attribute__((naked))` is not currently supported on x86 or x86-64.